# WordPress 5.4 and higher: Filter posts by category 1 AND category 2 in API requests

Tags: categories, taxonomy, request-filter

We have a WordPress 5.4 instance that we query through it's API. I am hoping to find a solution for the following problem that works with newer versions as well.

What I need is an intersection when fetching posts by category: Each returned post needs to be in category 1 AND in category 2. As far as I know, this is not possible with a vanilla WordPress installation, though that may change in some later version.

This problem has been [discussed before](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251527/wp-rest-api-filter-by-category-1-and-category-2), and some plug-ins have been recommended to restore a `filter` query parameter that was supported in WordPress 4.6 and earlier versions. However, these plug-ins all seem to have been abandoned or not to do what I need.

I tried using the code from the [simplest of these plug-ins](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter), but it does not work: When filtering post with `?filter[categories]=1` I still get all posts, while `?categories=1` only gives me a few posts (as expected). I didn't even get to test a more complex query. The condition in this code snippet evaluates to true, so the `filter` param seems not to be recognized:

```
// Bail out if no filter parameter is set.
if ( empty( $request['filter'] ) || ! is_array( $request['filter'] ) ) {
    return $args;
}
```

What would be the simplest or most standard solution for us to make filtering for category 1 AND category 2 work?

Comment: Have you tried `?categories=1,2`?

Comment: I may not have expressed myself clearly: What I need is an intersection. Each returned post needs to be in category 1 AND category 2.